# API 4 problem while running composer

Tags: drupal, api, apiv4, composer, setup

everybody.
Since the installation of CiviCRM I have problems in composer.
Another installation, on the same VPS, is not causing any problems.

- The website is a Drupal based one (9.5.10)
- I started it from a Varbase profile
- CiviCRM is updated (5.64.0), the database too

Every time I launch composer it comes with errors like this:

```
Class Civi\Authx\Authenticator located in ./vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ext/authx/Civi/Authx/Authenticator.php does not comply with psr-0 autoloading standard. Skipping
```

I've read about this error but it's always related to PHP development. Why is it happening on this CiviCRM installation?